# Different Session between HttpHandler and WCF Services in Same Application

Tags: silverlight, wcf, session, httphandler

I'm having an issue getting an HttpHandler in my WCF Service Application to recognize the same session that a Silverlight client has for the WCF Services... that is:

1. User logs in via SL app to WCF Service - HTTPContext.Current.Session["user"] is created as IPrincipal
2. User successfully uses several other WCF services in same application, Security works
3. User goes to hit a method that invokes one of my HttpHanders - e.g. upload.ashx, and suddenly has a new sessionID

Now, the WCF Services all have:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

and the HttpHandlers all inherit from BaseHandler, which implements IHttpHandler and

```
IRequiresSessionState: BaseHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

and in the web.config for the app, i have my httpHandlers section (correctly?) set up:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="Upload.ashx" type="THR.STAISys.WCF.Upload" />
</httpHandlers>
```

So i have NO idea why they are not maintaining the same session... when hitting from a test aspx page, i can log in and correctly hit the handler, but when i've logged in via the SL app, i get one session ID, and hitting the handler i get a different session id... why would this be?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).